# SQLite How to fetch every column after the 5th

Tags: sql, sqlite

Lets say i have the following sql table named urls:

| url | redirect | revenue | realRevenue | clicksGermany | clicksUSA | clicksIndia |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| gaxktgq | google.com | 0.321 | 69.51 | 15 | 28 | 33 |
| oqjkgf1 | example.cn | 0.252 | 1424.3 | 1202 | 10 | 69 |
| gaxktgq | corn.shop | 1.242 | 42525.2 | 325525 | 1230 | 420 |

Now i want to fetch every column after realRevenue.
In this example you could just fetch by using the names of the columns that come after realRevenue but in my case there are way more fields that come after.

What query do i need?

Comment: `SELECT clicksGermany, clicksUSA, clicksIndia, .... FROM ....` There is no shortcut for this.

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: SQLite3 with Python @lemon

Answer (score 0):

If the fields you have correspond to the ones presented in your sample input, you should directly select those who are needed by you. If they're more than what we see here, check the next part.

As long as [SQLite does not support dynamic queries](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/281400/is-it-possible-to-create-dynamic-sql-statements-purely-in-sqlite), you can't create a query in an automatical way.

Although you can retrieve your table interesting fields by accessing the two tables "*sqlite_master*" and "*pragma_table_info*", that contains information regarding your table name and table fields respectively. By filtering on the table name and on the field id, you can have a list of all your fields.

```
SELECT p.name AS column_name
FROM sqlite_master             AS m
JOIN pragma_table_info(m.name) AS p ON m.name = 'tab' AND p.cid >= 4
```

Output:

| column_name |
| --- |
| clicksGermany |
| clicksUSA |
| clicksIndia |

But you can also have them prepared to be hardcoded into a `SELECT` statement, applying a `GROUP_CONCAT` on the concatenation of the table name and each table field.

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(m.name || '.' || p.name, ', ') AS fields
FROM sqlite_master             AS m
JOIN pragma_table_info(m.name) AS p ON m.name = 'tab' AND p.cid >= 4
```

| fields |
| --- |
| tab.clicksGermany, tab.clicksUSA, tab.clicksIndia |

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/b6GYTj1jzcXQnQbCA7G43q/2).

**Note**: This solution gets useful if your amount of fields is *very* big, such that writing all of them by hand becomes a time-consuming task.